# Unable to see file in bare repository at server site after pushing from local machine

Tags: git, debian

I have created a repository using "git init". I have also created a file in it. Then i clone this repo on local machine using "git clone". Then make changes to the file. I pushed it into a new bare repo at server using "git push". Now when i do "ls" in my new bare repo at server i was unable to see my file. But cloning this bare repo at local machine show my file and it is updated. My question is how to see my updated file at server site so that i can make changes at server site too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bare repository does not contain the "filesystem view" of the repository, but only the database.

the proper way to handle this is, to create a clone of the bare-repository on your server as well, where you can pull the changesets into, modify and push again to the (bare) repository.

you definitely want to keep the server-repository that is cloned to the different clients to be a *bare* repository.

Comment: @SumitRathore i put that last sentence, because pushing to a non-bare repository is asking for trouble. cf [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html) or [gitguys](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/shared-repositories-should-be-bare-repositories/)